# <HTMLSelectElement> usage in Typescript assignment

Tags: typescript

What's the function of `<HTMLSelectElement>` in the context of a TypeScript assignment?

```
let element = <HTMLSelectElement> document.querySelector('#id_name');
```

[Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) discusses the similarly named HTMLSelectElement *interface*, which seems different than the one used in TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is called a type assertion, you tell the compiler that what is returned from `querySelector` conforms to the `HTMLSelectElement` interface. The `HTMLSelectElement` interface is defined in lib.dom.d.ts